# How to change base dir with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have my whole project in directory **document_root** and I need to redirect there.

I've made simple rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ document_root/$1 [L]
```

which works just fine if I have

```
http://someurl.com/?foo=bar
```

but when I do

```
http://someurl.com/index.php?foo=bar
```

then it is redirected to the **document_root** version, so the url looks like

```
http://someurl.com/document_root/index.php?foo=bar
```

which I wanted to avoid.

Is there also any way how to block the **document_root** version and send it back to the shorter url version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !.*/index.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ document_root/$1 [L]
```